# buffer Error "out of bounds read / write" using mutex locks

Tags: locking, pthreads, mutex

I am working on using multiple threads in c and have come across this error while using segfault.stensal.com ... I can't seem to figure out why i'm having reading and writing out of bound errors.  Any direction here would be wonderful.  I know that locks are usually used when you have 2 or more threads modifying the same or similar data, so I will be modifying my buffer to act more like a stack, but for the time being, I wanted to make sure that my code worked with a simple array.

=========== Start of #0 stensal runtime message ===========

Runtime error: **[out-of-bounds write]**
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

````
-
- Writing 4 bytes to 0x818a6d4 will corrupt the adjacent data.
- 
- The memory-space-to-be-written (start:0x8189730, size:4000 bytes) is bound to 'buffer' at
-     file:/prog.c::14, 0
- 
-  0x8189730               0x818a6cf
-  +------------------------------+
-  |the memory-space-to-be-written|......
-  +------------------------------+
-                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
-           the write starts at 0x818a6d4 that is 4 bytes after the memory end.
- 
- Stack trace (most recent call first) of the write.
- [1]  file:/prog.c::86, 18
- [2]  file:/musl-1.1.10/src/thread/pthread_create.c::168, 17
- [3]  file:/musl-1.1.10/src/internal/c_abi_func.c::51, 8
-
```(56,208)

============ End of #0 stensal runtime message ============

=========== Start of #1 stensal runtime message ===========

  Runtime error: **[out-of-bounds read]**  
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

```stensal-diagnostic-info
-



My code is as follows:



#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (50)

typedef struct  {

        int pc1, pc2;

} Prodcons;

Prodcons buffer[500];

pthread_mutex_t lock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int pc1C;
int pc2C;


void *Producer();
void *Consumer();


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        pthread_t tid1;
        pthread_t tid2;
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        void *my_Ptr;

        if (argc == 1)
        {
                printf("usage: ./assn3 <number to factor>\n");
                return -1;
        }

        if (argc < 0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d must be >= 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
                return -1;
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1 ; i++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            buffer[i].pc1 = (atoi(argv[i + 1]));
            pc1C++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

        }

        pthread_attr_init(&attr);

        pthread_create(&tid1, &attr, Producer, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid2, &attr, Consumer, NULL);

        pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
        pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
}

void *Producer()
{

        for (int j = 0; j < pc1C; j++)
        {

            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock2);

            int myNum = buffer[j].pc1;




            if (myNum == 1)
            {
                    buffer[pc2C].pc2 = 1;
                    pc2C++;
            }

            while (myNum % 2 == 0)
            {
                   buffer[pc2C].pc2 = 2;
                   myNum = myNum/2;
                   pc2C++;
            }

            for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(myNum); i += 2)
            {
                    while (myNum % i == 0)
                   {
                            buffer[pc2C].pc2 = i;
                            myNum = myNum/i;
                            pc2C++;
                   }
            }


            if (myNum > 2)
            {
                   buffer[pc2C].pc2 = myNum;
                   pc2C++;
            }


            buffer[pc2C].pc2 = -1;

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock2);

        }

        pthread_exit(NULL);

}



void *Consumer()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pc1C; i++)
        {

                printf("%d: ", buffer[i].pc1);

                int j = 0;

                while (buffer[j].pc2 != -1 )
                {
                   //   printf("%d ",buffer[j].pc2);
                    j++;
                }

                printf("\n");
        }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
````

Comment: None of your code makes *any* sense at all. You need to consider what it is you are trying to achieve, and how multithreading is going to affect your approach. Case in point: your mutexes protect absolutely nothing, and consequently your code exhibits undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to objects from multiple threads. If you want to try again, I'd recommend starting by giving things meaningful names.

Comment: Thank you, I realized as I tried to read through my code how abstract it must have seemed.  I've posted a new question with more concise code, better variable names and have added comments to show what the code should be doing.  The new question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203711/dereferencing-a-non-pointer-error-when-passing-in-struct-pointer